# Is \addcontentsline robust, or do I need \protect?

Tags: macros

I'm defining a macro using `\addcontentsline`. However, I have no idea whether that command is robust or not. If it's fragile , `\protect` is mandatory. I have no idea whether a duplicate `\protect`, which `\protect`ing a robust command would result into, can produce any problems, so I assume it might do something just to be safe. Google just won't understand my search, so can someone help me on that detail?

In case someone is interested, I define a command that basically generalizes `\chapter`, `\section` etc. by putting the header level into a parameter pretty much like `\addcontentsline` does, however printing both to ToC and to the text like the sectioning commands do. It also allows part level. I already know how to basically do it, but need to know that little detail to actually program it out. (I've also yet to figure out how to get the header sizes for the levels, but I should already find info on that.)

Comment: `\protect` only makes a difference in a moving argument and it's hard to think that you would ever need `\addcontentsline` in such an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\protect` is not mandatory, or even recommended, with fragile commands, it is only needed if the command is used in a "moving argument". The most useful definition of a "moving argument" is slightly tautologous in this context as "an argument where `\protect` is needed) but basically moving arguments are arguments that get expanded or written to auxiliary files etc. So the argument to a section heading is a moving argument as it is written to the table of contents, but `\addcontentsline` itself is not likely to be used in such a context and so the question of whether it is robust or not doesn't really matter (as `\protect` is just `\relax` and does nothing in contexts other than moving arguments.)

Technically it is fragile, but if you are using it where `\protect` is not `\relax`, then something is probably wrong with the expansion order in the code, so prefixing by `\protect` is unlikely to ever be useful.

Comment: If it's fragile, I'll probably insert `\protect` just in case the expansion side of `\newcommand` (where I obviously use it, as I define a macro expanding to it) is a moving argument.

Comment: @EgorHans as I tried to explain, this is not really a good idea. Although most likely it makes no difference, if it ever does make a difference, something else is wrong and adding `\protect` here wouldn't be the right fix

Comment: @EgorHans `\newcommand` does no expansion.

Comment: OK, that's good to know. `\newcommand` is safe on that matter, noticed and memorized.

Answer (score 0):

After asking this, I browsed some further and found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands), the accepted answer on which seems to imply that `\protect`ing a robust command shouldn't do anything bad. In fact, that answer even suggests `\protect`ing all macros in case of error, which most definitely wouldn't be failproof if `\protect` weren't safe on robust commands. So having that information, my question becomes obsolete, as I know I'm on the safe side with `\protect`.

Comment: In case you wonder, I found the answer. I just can't accept my own answer yet.